# Counting files in directory

Tags: bash, find, sh

For some reason I seem to be having some formatting issues here. I'm trying to count the number of files in a jvm directory. I'm counting to compare against a known integer (ie the file should contain 51 files). The purpose is to make sure all the files are present. Basically it was a quick and dirty way to see if all files were present after download and un-tar as part of an installer. Originally I was going to use MD5 (which in some ways is more ideal as it will check for file corruption), but it will take too long and I cant take an MD5 of a directory so I was either have to retar the directory in question before calculating or caluclate each file which is just getting too cumbersome. I cant use diff either as there is no identical directory to compare against yet. All it is doing is checking that all the required files are present before beginning install. If someone can recommend a different strategy, I am open ears. If not, this simple solution will work if I get it working correctly. Here is all I did:

First find the number of files in the jvm folder (should always be 51 as we provide the jvm container)

```
COUNT=$(find jvm -type f | wc -l)
if [ "$COUNT" = "51" ]; then
  YAY
else
  OOPS
fi
```

For some reason, I think the output of the first command contains whitespace and as a result is storing all of it as a string. When the compare occurs, it fails.

This script must run in both bash and sh

Comment: Have you printed out the value of `$COUNT` to see what it contains? Why is md5 (or some other more modern) hashing function too difficult here? Is processing of the local data for hashing really going to dominate the download and installation process running times in a meaningful way?

Comment: The JVM 8 container is not too big, but for backwards compatibility with a few systems that cant use the JVM 8 yet, we have to include OpenJDK7 which is huge in comparison (50+ MB) Calculating the MD5 for each file there would be pointlessly time consuming. Need a better solution.

Comment: Your script works well for me, even with whitespaces in file names. Have you tried printing the content of `$COUNT` variable?

Answer (score 1):

To count files on Unix systems properly use this script:

```
c=0
while read -d '' line; do
    ((c++))
done < <(find jvm -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)

echo $c
```

This script will take care of filename with spaces or new lines as well.

Comment: `find jvm -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "a" | wc -c` also works if the `printf` option of find is available.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a string comparison:

```
if [ "$COUNT" = "51" ]
```

Since `$count` is a number, do a numeric comparison instead with `-eq`:

```
if [[ $COUNT -eq 51 ]]
```

This way, the white space in front of `$COUNT` doesn't affect the comparison. Also not the double square brackets. This is now preferred over the single square brackets. It's less prone to errors when you forget quotes.

Comment: `$COUNT` may as well be treated as a string. Then this is a string comparison. Works well for me. I don't think problem comes from here.

Comment: The problem is that `$COUNT` end up being equal to `"    51"` and he's comparing that string to `"51"`. The padded whitespace in front of `$COUNT` is causing the problem. The OP can remove the quotes around the strings, and then the shell will ignore whitespace.

Comment: With `-l` option, I have no spaces/tab (using `wc (GNU coreutils) 8.20`). But depending on OP's system, maybe it could cause a problem indeed. @Atomiklan: does `wc -l some_file` gives you tab/spaces?

Comment: `wc -l` from Solaris 11 has leading whitespaces.

Comment: So does the Mac. In the standard POSIX implementation, `wc -l` always has a leading whitespace because it allows numbers to be aligned. Gnu doesn't do this with STDIN. I've seen a few shell scripts break due to things like this. Bad GNU. No donut for you!

Comment: Leading whitespaces were removed from GNU wc 5.0.1 to 5.0.90. Excerpt from changelog: "2003-07-20  Paul Eggert  <eggert@twinsun.com>: [...] If only one count is printed, it is guaranteed to be printed without leading spaces."

Comment: Yes you are correct, the whitespace is indeed there on Ubuntu Linux and pfSense FreeBSD

Comment: I get [[: not found in sh shell

Comment: Did you put `#! /bin/bash` on the top of your script? If not, it's using the _default_ shell which could be ash, dash, or even the original Bourne shell. You can revert back to  `[` if `[[` is giving you problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the simple:

```
count=`find jvm -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | grep -zc '.'`
```

- the find

  - search for all `files` in the `jvm` directory
  - and print them as `null terminated` strings.
- the grep

  - the `-z` says grep to accept `null terminated` strings as input (each such string is one "line")
  - the `-c` counts the matchd "lines"
  - match for any character `.`
- the backticks are `bash` and `sh` compatible
- the script is immune to any special character in the filename (e.g. can contain `\n` too)

With this you can also `filter&count` filenames, like

```
count=`find jvm -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | grep -zc '\.java'`
```

to count files ending with `.java` and such.